# Find which child view was tapped when using UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ipad

How do I know on which of the the child views an event occurred when using UIGestureRecognizers?

According to the documentation:

> A gesture recognizer operates on
>   touches hit-tested to a specific view
>   and all of that view’s subviews.

As far as I can see, the 'view' property is

> The view the gesture recognizer is
>   attached to.

which will be the parent view.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

This will find the innermost descendant view at the event's location. (Note that if that child view has any interactive internal private grandchildren this code will find those too.)

```
UIView* view = gestureRecognizer.view;
CGPoint loc = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:view];
UIView* subview = [view hitTest:loc withEvent:nil];
```

In Swift 2:

```
let view = gestureRecognizer.view
let loc = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(view)
let subview = view?.hitTest(loc, withEvent: nil) // note: it is a `UIView?`
```

In Swift 3:

```
let view = gestureRecognizer.view
let loc = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)
let subview = view?.hitTest(loc, with: nil) // note: it is a `UIView?`
```

Comment: Awesome! This will help with a lot more than just this case :)

Comment: Just wanted to add that `hitTest:withEvent:` will go as far down the tree of children as it can. If there are any subviews, or subviews of subviews, that you want to ignore, you can set `userInteractionEnabled = NO` on those views.

Comment: What if we want to only go down one level?

Comment: @JohnD. Find `.superview` iteratively until reaching the original `view`.

Answer (score -1):

For future users... 
I have got a better option now when world is not using obj-c anymore...

`[sender view]`

use it this way:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * objTapGesture = [self createTapGestureOnView:myTextField];

[objTapGesture addTarget:self action:@selector(displayPickerView:)];
```

// add these methods

```
-(void)displayPickerView:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[sender view];
    NSLog(@"tag=  %ld", (long)textField.tag);
}

-(UITapGestureRecognizer*)createTapGestureOnView:(UIView *)view
{
    view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    return tapGesture;
}
```

Comment: -[UIGestureRecognizer view] returns a view it's attached to (per spec); OP is interested in the subview of that view.