# List of all the subviews a UITouch event is forwarded to

Tags: subview, uitouch, uitapgesturerecognizer, first-responder

I have a UIScrollView with some views inside. When I tap on it I want to be able to understand if the touch occurred in an clean area or in area where there is a subview. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a possible solution in [Find which child view was tapped when using UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788870/find-which-child-view-was-tapped-when-using-uitapgesturerecognizer)

so, after registering a *UITapGestureRecognizer* using:

```
//        // Intercept all the taps inside the view
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                 initWithTarget:self
                                                 action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

it's enough to include this code:

```
- (void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    UIView* view = recognizer.view;
    CGPoint loc = [recognizer locationInView:view];
    UIView* subview = [view hitTest:loc withEvent:nil];

    NSLog(@"HIT! in %@",NSStringFromClass([subview class]));
}
```