# Detecting UIView grid squares where a UIPanGestureRecognizer begins and ends

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm designing a game that takes place on a grid.  The grid needs to respond to pan gestures that begin in one square and end in another.  I have a custom view controller class called `GameVC` which contains the grid of UIViews of subclass `GameGridSquare`.  I want the game to perform an action when, for example, a pan gesture begins and ends in neighboring squares.  I have a storyboard wired with properties that name each square by row and column: self.A1, self.A2, ... self.H7, self.H8.  As a pan gesture is recognized, I want the `GameVC` to receive the two `GameGridSquares` where `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` so it can determine the appropriate action, like so:

```
-(void)validatePanGestureFrom:(GameGridSquare*)beginSquare 
                           to:(GameGridSquare*)endSquare
```

What's the best way to do this?  My recognizers are functional and returning coordinates, but I think I need to explore hit-testing.

If I add recognizers to the individual `GameGridSquares`, I get undesired results.  For example, a pan that begins in A1 and ends in B2 would be recognized by A1 alone.  This suggests that I need a pan recognizer on `GameVC` that can detect when the gesture begins and ends in separate subviews.

From what I've read, I believe that the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol may be helpful here.  I also understand that a custom `UIPanGestureRecognizer` subclass would allow me to override hitTest:withEvent but I'm not sure where to even begin with that.  Any ideas about how I should approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was what I was after:

[Find which child view was tapped when using UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788870/find-which-child-view-was-tapped-when-using-uitapgesturerecognizer)

```
UIView* view = gestureRecognizer.view;
CGPoint loc = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:view];
UIView* subview = [view hitTest:loc withEvent:nil];
```