# Identifying who performed the gesture in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 12 UIViews and an array of outlets for them and I'm adding gesture recognizers to them in code:

```
for (PlayingCardView *card in self.cardButtons) 
    [card addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cardTouch:)]];
```

But when a tap happens and the cardTouch method gets called, how can I identify which of my UIViews has been tapped?

Comment: See if this works for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788870/find-which-child-view-was-tapped-when-using-uitapgesturerecognizer

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know which gesture recognizer called my cardTouch method, so I can't access it's .view property. Is there any way to pass the sender to my cardTouch method?

Comment: Yes, it says it in the post. Access the .view property. Many times frameworks include common references you would need to access as properties on another class. I would suggest reading the developer documentation as well as searching Google. Here is a link to the official Gesture Recognizer documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is `cardTouched:`. The colon means it takes an argument. In this case, the argument will be the gesture recogniser that sends the action. Each gesture recogniser is attached to a separate card view, so the `view` property of the sender will be the touched card.