# Manipulate target of UIGestureRecognizer in action function

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

When I click on a view, I would like for that view to change dimensions. TO do that, I need to find the view that has been clicked. Is there any way I could access the view in the function?

Here is the code i've written so far

```
var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("recognizeTapGesture:"))
    buttonView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


func recognizeTapGesture(sender: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    var something = self
    println("button tapped")

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Nikhil

Comment: Already asked :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788870/find-which-child-view-was-tapped-when-using-uitapgesturerecognizer

Comment: You want to access sender.view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIGestureRecognizer` has a `view` property that returns the view it was added to.