# Reordering sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, move, sections

I have UITableView with sections and rows(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Xuq.jpg). I know how enable reordering for rows, but i dont know how implement reordering for sections.
I need add reordering control to sections(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgLV7.jpg) and then when user touch this control, rows under section should flops. After that user can move section to new place.
After read topics on stackoverflow and other sites, i dont find any good idea how implement something like this.
I thought about implement sections through cells, but in this case i can't flop rows under section for further moving to new place.
If you have any idea how implement this – give me advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native functionality to achieve what you want. If I understand correctly you would want to collapse a whole section of rows and then start dragging the "header" around. If you want to do this on your own I would suggest starting with a pan gesture recognizer which triggers on the header button.

The gesture should be relatively obvious. After it starts on the header you need to track position using `locationIn` in your table view.

To collapse rows all you need to do is modify your table view cells with appropriate animation like:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteSections([myIndexPath], with: .top) // Maybe experiment with animation type
// Modify whatever you need to correspond this change in the data source
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Since you will be removing the section you will also be removing the view (header) which has the gesture recognizer. That means it might be better adding the gesture to the table view directly or its superview even. You will need to force it to trigger only when one of those buttons on headers is pressed. You can get some idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788870/find-which-child-view-was-tapped-when-using-uitapgesturerecognizer) about it. The rest is unaffected by this change.

At this point you will probably need to create an extra view which represents your section stack and follows your finger. This should be pretty easy if you add it as a subview and manipulate it's center with pan gesture recognizer `locationIn` in it's superview:

```
movableSectionView.center = panGestureRecognizer.location(in: movableSectionView.superview!)
```

So up to this point you should be able to grab a section which collapses all cells and be able to drag the "section stack" view around. Now you need to check where in table view your finger is to know where to drop the section. This is a bit painful but can be done with `visibleCells` and `tableView.indexPath(for: )`:

```
func indexPathForGestureRecognizer(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> IndexPath {
    let coordinateView: UIView = tableView.superview! // This can actually be pretty much anything as long as it is in hierarchy
    let y = recognizer.location(in: coordinateView).y
    if let hitCell = tableView.visibleCells.first(where: { cell in
        let frameInCoordinateView = cell.convert(cell.bounds, to: coordinateView)
        return frameInCoordinateView.minY >= y && frameInCoordinateView.maxY <= y
    }) {
        // We have the cell at which the finger is. Retrieve the index path
        return tableView.indexPath(for: hitCell) ?? IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) // This should always succeed but just in case
    } else {
        // We may be out of bounds. That may be either too high which means above the table view otherwise too low
        if recognizer.location(in: tableView).y < 0.0 {
            return IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        } else {
            guard tableView.numberOfSections > 0 else {
                return IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) // Nothing in the table view at all
            }
            let section = tableView.numberOfSections-1
            return IndexPath(row: tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section), section: section)
        }
    }
}
```

Once the gesture recognizer ends you can use this method to get the section you are dropping your items into. So just:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
// Modify whatever you need to correspond this change in the data source
tableView.insertSections([indexPathForGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer).section], with: .bottom)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

This should basically be enough for reordering but you might want to show in table view where the dragged section is. Like having a placeholder at the end of the section in which the stack will be dropped into. That should be relatively easy by simply adding and then moving an extra placeholder cell reusing `indexPathForGestureRecognizer` to get a position for it.

Have fun.

Comment: Wow, so detailed and useful answer. Thank you for help. I will try to understand and realize it.